# database update sql not affecting database

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server-2005

i have this code to update a database, but when ever i run it with the right data, it executes without errors but the databse is not update

```
 Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(My.Resources.conn_str)
 Dim SQL As String = "Update vehicle SET make=@make,reg_no=@reg_no,model=@model,year=@year,type=@type,last_service=@last_service Where (id = @id)"
        conn.Open()
        Try
            Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQL, conn)
            Try
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@make", strMake)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg_no", strRegnNum)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", strModel)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", intYear)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", strType)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_service", LastService)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID.ToString)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Dispose()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return ex.Message
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        Finally
            conn.Dispose()
        End Try
```

can anyone help me with the reason its not working, as i don get an error message?

thanks

EDIT
i replaced the **cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()** with

```
Dim intAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Debug.Print(intaffected)
```

and i get 1 in the output window

Comment: it wasn't there before, i was just playing around with this and it still dosent work

Comment: already deleted :-), the query does not seem to be wrong. Take a look at the ID, it is written in capital letters, all the other variables are in camel case, could it be, that your "ID" is the wrong "ID"

Comment: Are you sure you're passing in a valid ID? Try debugging, note the value of all the parameters and execute the exact same statement in an SQL client, does the DB update? Finally, are you checking/connected to the SAME DB (I have been guilty of this before!)

Comment: What is `conn_str`? How are you verifying that the update didn't happen? Most times I see this symptom, they were using Express with user instances / attachdbfilename and the instance with the database being updated was not the same instance that was being checked.

Comment: Do you have access to SQL Profiler?

Comment: @PhilippMehrwald the id is an integer

Comment: mssql is returning 1 if there was 1 row to update, no mater if a value was changed or not (if the values were already the same), so it seems like your code is working and you need to search somewhere else.

Comment: i have a longshot: you have a form in which you want to change values. On the server click event you are saving the values (thats the snippet). In the page load, you are loading the values for the form?! Page load would override the entered values before you store it... As I said just a guess, happened to me more than just one time.

Comment: i ran sql profiler and got this `exec sp_executesql N'Update vehicle SET 
make=@make,reg_no=@reg_no,model=@model,year=@year,type=@type,last_service=@last_service Where id = @id',N'@make 
nvarchar(3),@reg_no nvarchar(8),@model nvarchar(8),@year nvarchar(4),@type nvarchar(5),@last_service datetime,@id 
nvarchar(1)',@make=N'Man',@reg_no=N'GC7654KJ',@model=N'Power450',@year=N'2005',@type=N'Truck',@last_service=''2011-06-01 
00:00:00:000'',@id=N'3'`. how do i use it to debug the error from this output?

Comment: @PhilippMehrwald am not sure that is correct. if no rows where affected, it wouldn't return 1, would it?

Comment: I notice that the values passed from the textbox is the original loaded into it, not the one filled in

Comment: From your SQL Profiler output, are the values in the parameters the data you entered?  Also, I am noticing the ID.ToString has forced your @id parameter to an nvarchar(1) instead of an int. SQL should have an implicit conversion that allows this, but I would change your code have this parameter as an int and see if that does it.

Comment: @DaveSimione not its not, how do i fix this?

Comment: After seeing your comment that the values are the same as the originals, it sounds as though @PhilippMehrwald is correct that you are restoring your original values, most likely in Page_Load if this is a web forms app.  As for fixing the ID datatype issue, just use cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID)

Comment: Assuming this is a web forms app, make sure wherever you are loading your data into the textboxes is inside a "if not Page.IsPostback() then"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. If you have access to SQL Profiler, you can see the query, the values, the result, any triggers, any transactions, etc.  This is the easiest way to identify what is going on.
2. If you don't have access to Profiler, update your query to include the OUTPUT clause, and return the values from inserted.* and deleted.* into a SqlDataReader using ExecuteReader.  Check the results.
3. If the id is an int, don't use ID.ToString() on the parameter.AddWithValue.  Use the integer itself, as the AddWithValue method with a string value could cause the ID parameter to be configured as a varchar/nvarchar.

Comment: Profiler for sure.  I start a good quarter of my debugging and reverse engineering with profiler.